# Splitting Digits of a Number into an Integer Array

Tags: java, math, split, integer

I'm looking to split an `integer`, so I can tell if it is a *Dudeney Number* and/or factorial number. I have made an attempt but feel like it could be better, but don't know how to improve it. The main problem I am trying to fix, is the amount of code written to accomplish the task. Assuming number entered is 3579.

```
int number = input.nextInt();
double temp = number;
int counter = 0;

while(temp >1){
    temp/=10;
    counter++;
}
```

This code simply just gets the length of the number, so I can make the array the appropriate length.

```
int[] numberSplitted = new int[counter];
int divisor = (int)Math.pow(10, (counter-1)); // = 1000 in this case

int locationInArray = 0;

while(divisor != 0){
    int result = number / divisor;   //result = 3579/1000 = 3;
    number %= divisor;               // number = 3579%1000 = 579; 
    divisor /= 10;                   // divisor = 100;
    numberSplitted[locationInArray] = result;
    locationInArray++;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [`Math.log10()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10-double-)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to a `String` and split that into individual numbers. After you do that, you can use a `for` loop and convert the contents of the `String` array to `int` one by one.

```
String[] stringNumber = Integer.toString(number).split("(?<=.)"); 
for(int i = 0; i < stringNumber.length; i++) {
    numberSplitted[i] = Integer.valueOf(stringNumber[i]);
}
```